# How should I alter my code for my "string of Text & Numbers to Morse code" converter for the code to be able to run?

Tags: matlab, user-interface, morse-code

[push button callback to convert to Morse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfhYx.jpg)

Hi, I have a problem, I'm supposed to create a GUI in MATLAB which converts letter & numbers into Morse code but my code wouldn't run, the attached image link above is for the push button callback. Also it says that the 'Morse' underlined in red needs to be preallocated for speed as it changes size every loop iteration. How should I approach this? Thanks..

Also, should I include anything under my edit1 and edit2 callbacks? Since edit1 is just for entering the input of numbers and letters and edit2 is just to output the Morse code. Thanks again!
[edit1 & edit2 callbacks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05Z4D.png)

Comment: Please don’t post images of code, copy-paste the code directly into the question. This makes the post more accessible to those using screen readers or small screens, are behind a firewall that blocks Imgur, etc. and makes it easier to answer your question by not having to type in your code to try out suggested solutions.

Answer (score 1):

1. "Morse" changes size every loop iteration. First of all, let's define 2 variables.

```
Morse_1 = [];
Morse_2 = zeros(1,100);
```

(I'm taking the liberty of defining matrices instead of strings, but that's easier to explain this concept). You are basically saying that `Morse_1` is a blank variable that can be filled, while `Morse_2` has fixed dimensions. The dimensions of blank variables like `Morse_1` (pardon me if I'm not using the correct names, but I think blank variable explains it quite well) are flexible. This means that doing

```
Morse_1(1,101) = 1
```

will work (`Morse_1` will be a 101-dimensional vector with 100 zeros and a 1 at the 101st position). Doing

```
Morse_2(1,101) = 1
```

will work as well, but you might end up with too many unused elements if you largely overestimate the dimensions (e.g. zeros(1,1000) but your message actually only reaches a few hundred).

In your case, I'd use a blank variable, since you don't really know beforehand how long your coded message is going to be (even if you knew the number of characters in your original string, the coded message would be 5 times longer if it were all '9's than all 'e's). This warning is really useful when dealing with 1000x1000 matrices, but for processing strings I'd ignore it.

To sum it up, I'd use a blank variable if you have *no* idea how long it'll get, or if your code can't handle a variable length, or if you don't want to worry about calculating exactly how many elements are needed. On the other hand, I'd use fixed dimensions if your code *needs* a properly dimensioned array, or if you're working with very large arrays. For a lot of cases, though, you really won't notice the speed difference (filling a blank array might take 0.01s, while filling a fixed dimension one might take 0.001s. Unless you're doing this a thousand times (why??), it's literally unnoticeable).

2. Personally, I'd change the way this loop works using `strrep()` like this:

```
for i=1:length(alphabet) %alphabet = 26 letters+10 numbers+space, 37 characters in total
    original_message = strrep(original_message,alphabet{i},morse_alphabet{i});
end
```

`strrep(a,b,c)` finds the substrings `b` inside `a` and replaces it with `c`. In your case, alphabet is the same as the dictionary `chars`, and morse_alphabet is the same as the dictionary `code`.

As for the callbacks, I don't really know about it, so I can't help you with that.

Comment: @CrisLuengo huh, I just assumed it wouldn't work. Matlab really is lenient. Thank you. Edited the answer.

Comment: `[]` is the same as `zeros(0,0)`, an array with 0 elements. Other than the number of elements, there is no difference between those two arrays. `[]` is typically referred to as an "empty array".